# How could I wire up my Services without using DI like guice?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am currently using guice with play, so in my controllers I inject a service like:

```
class UserController @Inject()(userService: UserService) ....
```

And my service looks like:

```
class UserServiceImpl @Inject(userDao: UserDao) extends UserService {

}
```

My UserDao uses slick for database access.

My question is, if I didn't want to use slick, exactly how could I write up my dependencies?

Currently my UserService is a singleton.

Can someone show me how I could wire things up without using DI?   I know someone is going to say '**use the cake pattern**' but pratically can someone show how to do this from within the playframework?

Comment: I understand the will to have a 'services façade' with the less possible trace of underlying implementation, so that you could update internal code without impact on the rest of app calling it, but are you in a situation where there can be several impl of same services/features at the same time? Could impl of services be choosen dynamically/by config?

Comment: My understanding is that Guice is the future of DI in play, so maybe using it now isn't so bad.

Comment: @acjay where did you get that impression from? interesting!

Comment: Play will be using Guice for DI around plugins/modules, but that doesn't mean it fit each and every situation. As DI used to be hype/buzzword in vanilla Java community, in Scala it's better to use it if you need it, because at some point it lessen compiler checks.

Comment: @publicstatic There's a long thread on it here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework-dev/9IZOhzQ8e9Y

Comment: This is a complete integration test for controller with Play farmework and Guice: https://github.com/luongbalinh/play-mongo/blob/master/test/controllers/UserControllerTest.scala